# How to handle data set having multiple tables in Dotnet core using Fromsql()

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating WebApi using dot net core

I have created procedure which returns data from 2 tables AS:-

```
select * from table1
select * from table2
```

I have model list as:-

```
public class ModelList
{
public model1 m1 { get; set; }
public model2 m2 { get; set; }
}
```

i am executing procedure and receiving result in mode list as:-

```
List<ModelList> ML= new List<ModelList>();
ML= db.ModelList.FromSql("EXECUTE [dbo].[usp]").ToList();
```

I am not getting the result of those two tables in these two separate objects.

it works with single table but not with multiple.

please suggest where i am making mistake ?

or whether it is doable in dot net core ?

Comment: In that case you need to use ADO.NET and handle multiple result set

Comment: @H.Herzl there is limited functionality of ADO.net  in CORE.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation will provide the desired result:

```
public ModelList ExecuteMultiple(string query){

             using( IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING)){
                try{
                    connection.Open();
                    var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query);
                    var modelList = new ModelList();
                    modelList.m1 = multi.Read<model1>();
                    modelList.m2 = multi.Read<model2>();
                    return modelList;
                }
                catch( Exception ex){
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }finally{
                    connection.Close();
                }
             }

             return null;
         }
```

Usage:

```
var modelList = ExecuteMultiple("EXECUTE [dbo].[usp]");
```